# How can I add more than one controls like UITextField and UIButton with UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I used to write [myTableView.contentView addSubView:myTextField]

But I can add only one control at the same time!

Is there anyway to add textfield and button at the same time??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution for this,
What I do, was, Add a view and in that view I added a TextField and Button, and finally added that view into particular section of cell of my TableView.
What you need to do is set proper frame for your view and controls.
So simple!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to add them at the same time?, if the problem is that you can only see one or the other, then all you have to do is modify their frame so they don't overlap.

There isn't a way to add them both on a single line, but you can of course add both using 2 lines.

Comment: I got my solution!! We can do it at the same line too. Thanks:)

Comment: If you are using a solution other than what was posted here, please post it for others to see.